# How to set decimal precision for value in JSON column in EF 7

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a table with a JSON column.

For example, I have the following model:

```cs
public class TableA
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;} = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemName {get;set;}
    public double ItemValue {get;set;}
}
```

In Fluent API I would describe this relationship as:

```cs
internal sealed class TableAConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableA> builder)
    {           
        ...

        builder.OwnsMany(o => o.Items,
            ms => { ms.ToJson(); });
    }
}
```

After generating the migration and updating the database it shows the warning message:

> No store type was specified for the decimal property 'ItemValue' on
> entity type 'Item'. This will cause
> values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default
> precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type
> that can accommodate all the values in 'OnModelCreating' using
> 'HasColumnType', specify precision and scale using 'HasPrecision', or
> configure a value converter using 'HasConversion'.

But you can't specify it via IEntityTypeConfiguration.
**Is there another way to specify precision?**

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `OwnsMany`, you can configure individual properties of your JSON model. An example that would fit your use-case:

```cs
internal sealed class TableAConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableA> builder)
    {           
        ...

        builder.OwnsMany(o => o.Items, ms =>
        {
           ms.ToJson();
           ms.Property(x => x.ItemValue).HasColumnType("FLOAT"); // Or DECIMAL(.., ..)
        });
    }
}
```

An other option is to use the `ColumnAttribute` in the model itself:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "FLOAT")] // Or DECIMAL(.., ..)
    public double ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```